# Why is the quantum Fisher information $J_f=[f(\frac43-f)]^{-1}$ for maximally entangled qubit pairs?

Tags: quantum-operation, quantum-fisher-information, quantum-metrology

I am reading paper [Channel Identification and its Impact on Quantum LDPC Code Performance](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221661424_Channel_Identification_and_its_Impact_on_Quantum_LDPC_Code_Performance) where the authors discuss the scenario where the decoder of a Quantum LDPC code uses an estimation of the depolarization probability of the channel in order to correct the errors.

When doing so, they establish the quantum Cramer-Rao bound in terms of the Fisher information. The Fisher information is defined as

$J_f = \mathrm{Tr}(\rho_f L_f^2)$,

where $L_f$ is the symmetric logarithmic derivative $2\partial_f \rho_f=L_f\rho_f+\rho_f L _f$. They then state that when the probe for the estimation is an unnetangled pure quantum state, such Fisher information can be proved to be $J_f = [f(2-f)]^{-1}$, and if the probe is a maximally-entangled qubit pair, it equals $J_f=[f(\frac{4}{3}-f)]^{-1}$.

I have been trying to prove such equalities for those cases of the Fisher information, but I haven't been able to find something similar to it nor prove it.